# How to update object Array State and screen style on touchable item click in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a bit new to react native and I am having difficulty updating object Array State and screen style  on button item  click during run time  in react native

I tried using useState but the style does not change at run time on the touchable item click

Please advise me on the right way to change the screens view style on item click

see my code below

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, FlatList, View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';

export default function Loans({}) {
  const [selectedDurationId, setSelectedDurationId] = useState(1);
  const [selectedAmountId, setSelectedAmountId] = useState(1);

  const changeSelectedDuration = function (id) {
    console.log('before selected Duration');
    console.log(id);
    //change all the selecteds to no
    durationArray.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
      var x = (arrayItem.selected = 'no');
      console.log(x);
      setSelectedDurationId(id);
      updateDataArray(durationArray, selectedDurationId);
      console.log('after selected Duration');
    });
  };

  const changeSelectedAmount = function (id) {
    console.log('before selected Amount');
    console.log(id);
    //change all the selecteds to no
    loanAmountArray.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
      var x = (arrayItem.selected = 'no');
      console.log(x);
    });
    setSelectedAmountId(id);
    updateDataArray(loanAmountArray, selectedAmountId);
    console.log('after selected Amount');
  };

  const updateDataArray = function (array, id) {
    array.forEach(function () {
      //change selected to yes where id == id
      if (array.id === id) {
        var x = (array.selected = 'yes');
        console.log(x);
      }
    });
  };

  const loanAmountArray = [
    {
      id: 1,
      amount: '5,000',
      selected: 'yes',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      amount: '10,000',
      selected: 'no',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      amount: '20,000',
      selected: 'no',
    },
  ];

  const durationArray = [
    {
      id: 1,
      days: '30 days',
      rate: '3.3% Interest',
      selected: 'yes',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      days: '60 days',
      rate: '5% Interest',
      selected: 'no',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      days: '90 days',
      rate: '7% Interest',
      selected: 'no',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.contain}>
          <Text>Chose Loan Amount</Text>
          <FlatList
            numColumns={6}
            data={loanAmountArray}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
              console.log('index', index);
              return index.toString();
            }}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
              console.log('item', item);
              return (
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      changeSelectedAmount(item.id);
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      style={
                        item.selected === 'yes'
                          ? styles.textBoxSelected
                          : styles.textBox
                      }>
                      {item.amount}
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />

          <Text>Chose Payment Duration</Text>
          <FlatList
            numColumns={3}
            data={durationArray}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
              console.log('index', index);
              return index.toString();
            }}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
              console.log('item', item);
              return (
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={
                      item.selected === 'yes'
                        ? styles.durationViewPressed
                        : styles.durationView
                    }
                    onPress={() => {
                      changeSelectedDuration(item.id);
                    }}>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.interest}>{item.rate}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.days}>{item.days}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

here's the  style below

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  textBox: {
    marginTop: 13,
    marginBottom: 30,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 6,
    fontSize: 18,
    borderColor: '#1a2856',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
  },
  textBoxSelected: {
    marginTop: 13,
    marginBottom: 30,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 6,
    fontSize: 18,
    backgroundColor: '#1a2856',
    color: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
  },
  durationView: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
  },
  durationViewPressed: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    borderColor: '#1a2856',
    borderWidth: 5,
  },
  interest: {
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#1a2856',
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
  },
  days: {
    borderColor: '#1a2856',
    borderWidth: 5,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 6,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

Both `loanAmountArray` and `durationArray` are defined in the function body, so they are actually redeclared each render cycle, so any mutations you thought you did in the previous render cycle are wiped out. When this happens the style attribute is never able to match anything different each render.

## Solution

1. Since it seems you don't really update the elements of the array you can move the arrays out of the component. They can remain `const` and won't be redeclared each render.
2. Don't bother trying to update the `selected` property of each element in the array, you can easily derive the selected state from the `selectedDurationId` and `selectedAmountId` state values and the current `item.id` when rendering.
3. Use the [`extraData`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) prop to indicate the list should rerender.

Code:

```
const loanAmountArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    amount: "5,000",
    selected: "yes"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    amount: "10,000",
    selected: "no"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    amount: "20,000",
    selected: "no"
  }
];

const durationArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    days: "30 days",
    rate: "3.3% Interest",
    selected: "yes"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    days: "60 days",
    rate: "5% Interest",
    selected: "no"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    days: "90 days",
    rate: "7% Interest",
    selected: "no"
  }
];

export default function Loans({}) {
  const [selectedDurationId, setSelectedDurationId] = useState(1);
  const [selectedAmountId, setSelectedAmountId] = useState(1);

  const changeSelectedDuration = function (id) {
    setSelectedDurationId(id);
  };

  const changeSelectedAmount = function (id) {
    setSelectedAmountId(id);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.contain}>
          <Text>Chose Loan Amount</Text>
          <FlatList
            numColumns={6}
            data={loanAmountArray}
            extraData={selectedAmountId} // <-- prop used to rerender
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
              return index.toString();
            }}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      changeSelectedAmount(item.id);
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={
                        item.id === selectedAmountId // <-- match id property
                          ? styles.textBoxSelected
                          : styles.textBox
                      }
                    >
                      {item.amount}
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />

          <Text>Chose Payment Duration</Text>
          <FlatList
            numColumns={3}
            data={durationArray}
            extraData={selectedDurationId} // <-- prop used to rerender
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
              return index.toString();
            }}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={
                      item.id === selectedDurationId // <-- match id property
                        ? styles.durationViewPressed
                        : styles.durationView
                    }
                    onPress={() => {
                      changeSelectedDuration(item.id);
                    }}
                  >
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.interest}>{item.rate}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.days}>{item.days}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

## [Expo Snack Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/how-to-update-object-array-state-and-screen-style-on-touchable-item-click-in-rea)

[image]

Comment: Thanks drew, but still not working after taking out the object array constants from the loan function, the views still don't change at run time after the user presses the TouchableOpacity of either amount or duration. Please advise me on how to make the  style of the views update indicating the newly pressed option at runtime

Comment: @MIikeEps I see. I updated my answer and added a running Expo Snack demo. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks a billion. You have quite literally saved my life

Comment: Hi @Drew, Please help with question in below thrwead as well. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556738/unable-to-navigate-to-different-navigation-menu-while-using-mobx-for-state-stora